# NavigationView переключение страниц в области Content UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Столкнулся с проблемой переключения окон в области Content в новом NavigationView. Собственно, мне нужно переключение на другую страницу по нажатии на кнопку, которое бы находилось в области Content, а не перерисовывало всю страницу. В примере, приведенном Microsoft, они используют для переключения фрейм:

```
<Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Margin="24">
            <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <NavigationThemeTransition/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Frame.ContentTransitions>
        </Frame>
```

Но при попытке передать во ViewModel ContentFrame - возникает ошибка - NullReference. Какие существуют способы переключения страниц в Content?

Comment: "Но при попытке передать во ViewModel ContentFrame - возникает ошибка - NullReference" -- а что конкретно вы делаете, и что в вашем stack trace?

Comment: К счастью разобрался в чем была проблема. Я по старой памяти, как и в WinForms, передавал параметры через конструктор класса, когда как в UWP необходимо принимать параметры с помощью перегрузки OnNavigateTo(). Проблема исчезла, но у меня появился другой вопрос. Возможно ли как то поместить метод OnNavigateTo() во ViewModel, или он является обязательной жертвой Code Behind?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, я лично не знаю. Возможно, имеет смысл написать самоответ на _этот_ вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Для корректной передачи фрейма, необходимо использовать метод Navigate, вторым параметром которого является сам передаваемый фрейм. А приём фрейма должен осуществляться перегруженным методом OnNavigateTo.